# I found this question but didn't get the answer for it

Tags: bidah

The hadith of Abu Lahab's punishment being eased in Jahanam on Mondays for celebrating the Birth of the Prophet SAWAWS is very well known and is Sahih. You may find it in Sahih Bukhari and other Hadith books

I did not find this on sunnah.com, so I have some doubt about this. I would like to know:

The exact text of this hadith
The ruling on it (mawdoo' vs. da'eef vs. hassan vs. sunnah)
Which books and collections it's found in
Any statements of scholars on it